# Connect camera to the Android phone via cable

Tags: camera

When travelling I usually bring my camera for pictures and my Android phone for communication. Camera is better than the phone for pictures, since it works faster and has better quality sensor. But what if I want to send fresh pictures to someone? Then I need to transfer the files from the camera to my phone in some way. Since the camera doesn't have any wireless connection, the only way is to connect it to the phone is via cable.

I can of course purchase a micro-SD card and put it into an adapter to fit into my mini-SD slot in the camera and then put it without adapter into the phone. However, I would rather avoid this as exchanging micro-SD on my phone is not easy and requires me to open the case that is kept together with some fragile pieces of plastic. If I do this too often, it will break soon.

Comment: According to the FAQ, questions should not be about *electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones*.

Comment: What phone do you have? I don't know of any offhand that support USB host mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of phones that support USB host mode. You could check the compatibility list of the app "DSLR Controller" over here: http://dslrcontroller.com/devices.php

In the column "How to connect" are links to an adapter cable which enables you to connect a camera to your phone.

If your phone is listed there or you verify via outher sources that your phone supports USB host mode then you could try one of the cables listed there.

After that you would need an app that enables you to mount the camera storage so you can access it.

Today I ordered one of those cables and will try to connect a cardreader to my phone (Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000). Will post further updates once the cable arrives.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I would need later Android version for that. I am currently using 2.2 and it seems like no update is coming from my provider.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov: if your provider isn't going to update Android, you could always try loading a custom ROM that has a higher version, like CyanogenMod.

Comment: @masterjo I have a Xoom running 3.2 and a Galaxy S running 2.3.3, I can confirm that with no additional software teh Xoom will read pictures straight from a connected camera, but ignore USB card readers. Using the same cable on stock 2.3.3 on the Galaxy S, it totally ignores both the camera and the USB card reader.

Comment: @GAThrawn interesting.. hopefully I'll be able to achieve something. Are you running 2.3.3 stock or some other firmware/ROM?

Comment: @masterjo stock Samsung 2.3.3

Comment: @Logos: That would require to root my phone (HTC Desire) which would void my warranty. I do not want to do that before my warranty period is over, because as far as I have heard - rooting HTC Desire requires writing to one-time-write memory and can be detected even after unrooting. Please correct me if I am wrong.